# What does WarningLevel property do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am using this in my code , but i am not sure what it does exactly.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" WarningLevel="4" %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx **and** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7.aspx. Directly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.compiler.warninglevel%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifies the default compiler warning level; determines the level at which the language provider treats compilation warnings as errors.

```
[ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("warningLevel", DefaultValue = )]
[IntegerValidatorAttribute(MinValue = , MaxValue = )]
public int WarningLevel { get; }
```

Hope this helps